# Spring Cloud Config - @ConditionalOnProperty and @Configuration behavior

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I'm having some issues with `@ConditionaOnProperty` and `@Configuration` behavior not being updated based on the changes in the application properties (config file).

Here's what I have

1. Configuration

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class RandomRestConfig {

       @Value("${external.message.root.uri}")
       private String rootUri;

       @Bean
       @RefreshScope
       public RestTemplate randomRestTemplate() {
           return new RestTemplateBuilder()
           .rootUri(rootUri)
           .build();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Conditional service

   ```
   @Service
   @RefreshScope
   @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "external.message.enabled", havingValue = "true")
   public class RandomRestService {

       @Autowired
       @Qualifier("randomRestTemplate")
       private RestTemplate restTemplate;

       public String getMessageFromService() {
           final var response = restTemplate.getForEntity("/trips/trip-text", String.class);
           return response.getBody();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Usage via controller

   ```
   @RefreshScope
   @RestController
   public class MessageRestController {

       @Value("${message: No message found}")
       private String message;

       private RandomRestService randomRestService;

       public MessageRestController(Optional<RandomRestService> optionalRestService) {
           optionalRestService.ifPresent(service -> this.randomRestService = service);
       }

       @GetMapping("/external-message")
       String getExternalMessage() {
           if (randomRestService == null) {
           throw new RuntimeException("Invalid request - rest is disabled");
           }

           return randomRestService.getMessageFromService();
       }
   }
   ```

Now, what I'm trying to achieve are

1. Change the value of the `rootUri`. I changed it in the config file but it didn't take effect, the old URI is still in effect.
2. Change the value of `external.message.enabled` from `false` to `true`, but the service is still null in `MessageRestController`. I was expecting that the bean will be updated.

Now, with both scenarios, I manually triggered the actuator `/refresh` endpoint and both properties were visible in the response.

```
    [
        "config.client.version",
        "external.message.root.uri",
        "external.message.enabled"
    ]
```

Am I missing something? Or is it possible at all?
Thank you!

Comment: `private String rootUri;` doesn't change. Add it to a `@ConfigurationProperties` bean or move it to a parameter of `randomRestTemplate()`. `@RefreshScope` not needed on `RandomRestService`

Comment: How about `@ConditionalOnProperty`? Is there a way to have this updated?

Comment: My previous comment is how to do it.